# DataTables - custom AJAX request in fnServerData isn't working

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am initializing a dataTable and using ajax function to load the data.
Server side is spring mvc + hibernate.

Following is the code to initialize the data table

```
$('.hist_data').on('click', function(){
    $('.myTable').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/application-monitor/getTableData",
        "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            request = $.ajax({
                "dataType" : "json",
                "type" : "POST",
                "url" : sSource,
                "data" : aoData,
                "success" : fnCallback
            });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "id" },
            { "mData": "name" },]
    } );

});
```

/application-monitor/getTableData returns a list of object (a java bean having an id and name which are my colums).

When i run this, i don't see any data in the page also i used firebug to debug it but do not see any issues in initializing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Look at the *actual network traffic* - what is returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me as it is.

I created some basic markup like this:

```
<div class="hist_data">Click here</div>
<table class="myTable"></table>
```

And I made a test backend that returned json like this:

```
{"aaData": [
  {"id":"1","name":"One"},
  {"id":"2","name":"Two"}
]}
```

Combined with the javascript you provided, and some links to the jquery and dataTables scripts, that was all I had to do to make it work.

I suspect the problem is in your backend code. In particular, note that you should be returning an object with an *aaData* field containing the array of items. You can't just return the array by itself.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was with my json, aaData was not there in the JSON response....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but first of all you need check in firebug or devtools is data is correctly fetched. If yes then maybe your code is wrong. I copy this from documentation:

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) {
    oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax( {
        "dataType": 'json', 
        "type": "POST", 
        "url": sSource, 
        "data": aoData, 
        "success": fnCallback
   });
},//....
```

I don't know what is `request` in your code but try this code above to be sure.

Comment: i just debugged it using firebug, it not getting inside this function itself..function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings ) ......not sure where the problem is

Comment: Are you sure? Even after click it's not firing? Put `console.log` before ajax call and tell me if it's display in console.